# URL.openConnection returning different instance of HttpsURLConnection in different environments

Tags: java, url, networking, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection

I am trying to make an Https request in java with the below code snippet:

```
1. java.net.URL urlObject = new java.net.URL("/*my https url*/");
2. javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection HttpsURLConnection = (javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection)urlObject.openConnection();
```

At runtime in line2 the `urlObject.openConnection()` returns an instance of `sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection` which is typecasted to `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` and this works perfectly fine.

However, in one of the environment this does not work and gives the below exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
```

Here in line 2 `urlObject.openConnection()` returns an instance of `com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl` which cannot be typecasted to `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`.

Can someone help me understand why `urlObject.openConnection()` returns different instances of different classes in different environments. Is it something to do with the dependencies etc.

Additional Infos:

- I have read other stackoverflow answers regarding this. My objective here is to understand the underlying reason why this is happening which was not conveyed enough in other answers.
- One workarond I found was to use `com.sun.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection con = (com.sun.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();` in place of line 2. But `com.sun.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` is actually deprecated.
- Another similar workaround was to use Http instead of Https i.e use `java.net.HttpURLConnection = (java.net.HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();`...but then this is does not answer my question about why the problem is actually happening.
- I am using openJdk 8

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you are trying to cast it to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection? You can use the base class, URLConnection and perform operations.

Comment: I am using the methods like setRequestMethod and setRequestProperty which are not available for URLConnection but available for javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection